# Laravel 4 + pass variable to master layout

Tags: layout, laravel-4, laravel-blade

i'm trying to pass a variable to my 'master' layout :

```
//views/dashboard/layouts/master.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

<body>
  @yield('site.body');
  {{{ isset($test) ? $title:'Test no exists :) ' }}}
</body>
</html>
```

Now in my DashboardController :

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController
{
    public $layout = "dashboard.layouts.master"; 

    // this throw error : Cannot call constructor
    //public function __construct()
    //{
    //    parent::__construct();
    //    $this->layout->title = 'cry...';
    //} 

    // this throw error : Attempt to assign property of non-object 
    // and I understand it, coz $layout isn't an object

    //public function __construct()
    //{
    //    $this->layout->title = 'cry...';
    //} 

    public function action_doIndex()
    {
        $this->layout->title = 'this is short title';
        $this->layout->body = View::make('dashboard.index');

    }

    public function action_doLogin()
    {
        //$this->layout->title = 'this is short title'; // AGAIN ???
        $this->layout->body = View::make('dashboard.forms.login');
    }

    public function action_doN()
    {
       // $this->layout->title = 'this is short title'; // AND OVER AGAIN ?!?!
    }

}
```

I want set only ONCE the $title variable, and when I want to do it - overwrite it.
Now I must set the variable every time when I call another method :/

How to do that ? How to set $title variable only ONCE for this 'master' layout ??

Symphony2 have before() / after() method - what laravel got ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `View::composer()` or `View::share()` to "pass" variables to your views:

```
public function __construct()
{
    View::share('title', 'cry...');
}
```

This is a composer:

```
View::composer('layouts.master', function($view)
{
    $view->with('name', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->firstname : '');
});
```

If you need it on all your views you can:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('name', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->firstname : '');
});
```

You can even create a file for this purpose, something like `app/composers.php` and load it in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```